# How to create /usr/src/linux-headers-$KVERS from /usr/src/linux build

Tags: linux, kernel, debian

I've made a custom linux kernel for **Ubuntu Lucid** and a live ISO to be able to distribute it.

But I don't want to include the full Linux sources in the distribution, just the headers so that it will be possible to install and update kernel packages such as VirtualBox guest additions.
Is there a way to automatically create the headers from the source tree?

Comment: Why not perform the same operations as when creating a normal kernel package?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this.

Comment: Normal kernel packages generate a corresponding header package. Do the same, but with a custom configuration.

Comment: In the source tree I've run make menuconfig, then make, then make modules_install, then make install. Then I tried make headers_install but that still doesn't make it possible to build Virtualbox guest additions if I remove the source tree. Am I missing something obvious?